# Write foreach loop in session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach, smarty

I have a foreach loop that contains following code:

```
{foreach name=aussen item=products_data from=$products}
        <div class="cart-item clearfix">
            <div class="cart-item-inner clearfix">
                {if $products_data.IMAGE}<a href="{$products_data.LINK}"><img alt="" style="max-width: 40px; max-height: 40px; border: 0pt none; margin: 0px 10px 0px 0pt; float: left;" src="{$products_data.IMAGE}" /></a>{/if}
                <p><div id="testimg" style="display: none;">{$products_data.IMAGE}</div>{$products_data.QTY}{if $products_data.UNIT} {$products_data.UNIT}{else}x{/if} {$products_data.NAME}<br/><span class="price">{$products_data.PRICE}</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {/foreach}
        <div id="dropdown_shopping_cart_total">
            <span>{$txt.text_total} {$TOTAL}</span>
        </div>
        <p class="mwst-hint">{$UST} {if $SHIPPING_INFO}{$SHIPPING_INFO}{/if}</p>
        <div class="cart-button"><a class="button_blue button_set" href="{'shopping_cart.php'|xtc_href_link}"><span class="button-outer"><span class="button-inner">{$button.to_cart}</span></span></a></div>

    {else}
        <div class="cart-item clearfix">
            <div class="cart-item-inner clearfix">
                <p>{$txt.text_empty_cart}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It´s the content of a shopping cart dropdown menu. I got another file that contains the product listing on the site. It allows you to add something to the cart. There is an input field and a shopping cart button.

Now for some products i want a limit of how much you can buy at one time. This means i have to compare the value of the input field with the amount of products that are already placed in the shopping cart. The problem is that the `{$products_data.QTY}` is in another file than the input field and the addtocart button.

What i tried so far is to give the `{$products_data.QTY}` an ID and onclick on the addtocart button compare the input field with the DivID. The problem is that on the DivID is fixed, which means if i compare them it always compares the input field to the first DIV.

Now my idea was to get the products in the above foreach loop to the session, so i can somehow compare it at this point.

Someone has experience how to get a foreach loop to a session?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why is your code wrapped between curly braces? Is that some framework? If it is, I suggest that you edit your question and tag its name.

Comment: @wrxsti I don't think so, ember.js gets two curly braces each side, and this is... I don't know, looks like PHP syntax but has some weird stuff.

Comment: What kind of syntax are you even using? that is def not JS... if the data your trying to access is in a session variable then use the PHP global '$_SESSION'... and or print the PHP session data var into a JS var and save the JS var as a 'window.session' variable.

Comment: @AlanMachado Ahhh I see...I played with ember for a few days a while back, and it vaguely reminded me of that. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: `foreach name=aussen item=products_data from=$products` what in the name of God is this? I'm legitimately curious! If it's a framework I want to study it, seems very compact!

Comment: I think it's smarty template

Comment: Well it's a shopsystem called Gambio which works with PHP SMARTY-Tags

Comment: I found it very interesting, didn't know it! But just a hint, remember to tag it on your post so you can attract people that occur to be specialized on the subject and you may get help faster!

Answer (score 0):

Does a single item from the basket $products (product_data) have a unique productId or a unique productNumber? 
On a product page is this unique productId or productNumber available as well?
If this is the case then perhaps you could check the amount already in the shoppingbasket in your product page by using this id.

It might make it easier if you shoppingbasket products use the productId as key.

```
{$products = [
    productId1 => ['amount' => 2, otherinfo...], 
    productId2 => ['amount' => 1, otherinfo...]
]}
```

In this case you could simply check {$products[$productId]['amount']} before setting a maximum with html or js inside your product page. I assume the shoppingcart variable is available in your product page.

I understand this key-value way might nog be your way to go(if the framework doesn't work that way). So at least make sure the product array in your basket has the productId. You could then loop your basket and check if the product already exists and how many are in the basket.

```
{$products = [
    0 => ['id' => productId1, 'amount' => 2],
    1 => ['id' => productId2, 'amount' => 1]
]}

//loop products from shopping basket in product page
{foreach $products as $product}
    {if $product['id'] == $currentProduct['id']}
         //do something to limit the number to be ordered
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

This assumes a product can only exists once in the cart and uses amount as a counter. If a product can exists more than once, you first have to count the amount of times the product has been put into the shoppingcart first.

I used a smarty 3 loop. You can always change it to the smarty version you need.

What the exact variable is for the products in the session I can't tell you, it depends on your framework probably... I like to use print_r($arrayYouWantToSee) to see which items/keys/values are avialable to me for a certain array, perhaps you could use it too :)